# Many elements of <init-param>,how to determine their order?

Tags: html, servlets, jakarta-ee

there are three  in web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>user</param-name>
    <param-value>root</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>password</param-name>
    <param-value>1234</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>dept</param-name>
    <param-value>z0</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The result of each run is

```
password:1234
dept:z0
user:root
```

They are random loading, or what order?

Thank you seniors.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: I just want to know how it works

Comment: The order may depend on application server you are using. You can look into source code of the server, if the source is available, to find out, how is processing of web.xml implemented.